# left and right justify columns correctly in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dictionary where each key in the dictionary is associated with a dataframe.

```
    data['total_brands'] = pd.DataFrame({'total_brands': {0: 164}})
    data['new_portfolios_added'] = pd.DataFrame({'new_portfolios_added': {0: 3}})
    data['total_updated_portfolios'] = pd.DataFrame({'total_updated_portfolios': {0: 1}})
    data['family_per_brand'] = pd.DataFrame({'brand_name': {0: 'Morningstar',
  1: 'Vanguard',
  2: 'WisdomTree',
  3: 'State Street',
  4: 'First Trust',
  5: 'Franklin Templeton Investments',
  6: 'Logicly',
  7: 'Nuveen',
  8: 'Scott Burns',
  9: 'Paul Merriman',
  10: 'Fidelity',
  11: 'FlexShares',
  12: 'Alpha Architect',
  13: 'Rick Ferri',
  14: 'Craig Israelsen',
  15: 'Rajan Subramanian',
  16: 'Goldman Sachs',
  17: 'JPMorgan',
  18: 'Xtrackers',
  19: 'PIMCO',
  20: 'John Hancock',
  21: 'Hartford',
  22: 'Invesco',
  23: 'Schwab'},
 'family_per_brand': {0: 7,
  1: 6,
  2: 5,
  3: 5,
  4: 4,
  5: 4,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 2,
  9: 2,
  10: 2,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 0,
  17: 0,
  18: 0,
  19: 0,
  20: 0,
  21: 0,
  22: 0,
  23: 0}})
```

Now, i want to send all my data to an email in text format with in the body of the email with the data frames looking presentable.  I searched around stack overflow and found these functions to help with my case:

```
blanks = r'^ *([a-zA-Z_0-9-]*) .*$'
blanks_comp = re.compile(blanks)

def find_index_in_line(line):
    index = 0
    spaces = False
    for ch in line:
        if ch == ' ':
            spaces = True
        elif spaces:
            break
        index += 1
    return index

def pretty_to_string(df):
    lines = df.to_string().split('\n')
    header = lines[0]
    m = blanks_comp.match(header)
    indices = []
    if m:
        st_index = m.start(1)
        indices.append(st_index)

    non_header_lines = lines[1:len(lines)]

    for line in non_header_lines:
        index = find_index_in_line(line)
        indices.append(index)

    mn = np.min(indices)
    newlines = []
    for l in lines:
        newlines.append(l[mn:len(l)])

    return '\n'.join(newlines) if df.shape[0] > 1 else ':'.join(newlines)
```

Then I tried:

```
final = "\n".join(pretty_to_string(data[key]) for key in data.keys())
print(final)
```

Gives me the following output which is visually not appealing as you can see from the attachment.

[image]

Ideally i would want, 164 under total_brands, 3 under new_portfolios_added and 1 in total_updated_portfolios all aligned to the right
Ideally I would want the dataframe with the column "brand_name" aligned below the "total_updated_portfolios" tab

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps saving to a csv, then opening in excel, copying the table into email would be fastest / easiest.  That method often preserves the formatting you select, depending on your email client.

```
data.to_csv('newfilename.csv')
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.  I wanted to get the data frames aligned in that specific order.  I have to send my data frames via a slack channel.  its automated.  so manually doing this is not possible.

Comment: Got it, you mentioned sending it in an email body in your question, so I thought this might be a good shortcut.

Comment: @rajn _I have to send my data frames via a slack channel_ Doesn't the question talk about email, though? You're looking for output which is easy to read for human beings, right, not another program?

Comment: @AMC, sorry i meant email.  the funny thing is on outlook application, i can view the contents formatted correctly.  but on the web server its all indented weridly

Comment: @rajn Alright, can you confirm the whole human versus machine readable thing?